# Reset command for TextBoxes and Comboboxes

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel user form with a Reset command button for clearing the user fields.
My user form consists of Textboxes and combo boxes. I used below script to reset fields. The problem is it's not clearing the values in comboboxes coz i used `icontrol.name like "Txt*"`. I tried `"Txt*","Comb*"` but it is giving me an error

```
Private Sub CmdReset_Click()

Dim iControl As Control

For Each iControl In Me.Controls
If iControl.Name Like "Txt*" Then iControl = vbNullString
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What error is it giving you?

Comment: add " or iControl.Name Like "Comb*".

Comment: it worked thank you very much @Guest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more accuracy, you could probably use the following:

```
For Each iControl In Me.Controls
   If TypeName(iControl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(iControl) = "ComboBox" then iControl.Value = vbNullString
Next iControl
```